# Superuser default status active

Tags: django

i have a custom user model. where defaulst is_active=False

```
class User(AbstractUser)
is_active=False
```

I want to make an exception where superuser is always active

Comment: Your superuser not active in custom model? Have you checked it in admin panel?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by overriding `save` and checking the `is_superuser` status

```
class User(AbstractUser)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.is_superuser: self.is_active=True
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I got an error saying super' object has no attribute 'self'

Comment: Sorry, typo - try now (assuming you're using python 3+